# What's the differences between #selector() and Selector() in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

What is the difference between those two? What is `Selector`, and what is `#selector`?

[image]
[image]

Comment: See if this helps: https://medium.com/swift-programming/swift-selector-syntax-sugar-81c8a8b10df3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are same things, the purpose of `#selector()` syntax is to save you from the possible error in having to write a selector as a literal string, which is error-prone.

Comment: `Selector()` is old, only fill with String, can't check syntax error, but `#selector` is new, and it works like real class.